# problems with the values of the promise Promise { value }

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mysql2

I'm exporting a function where it returns the value of a query in mysql, when I do the path of the Json and the values that I assign from the function appear as Promise {value} (example Promise {61}), and I do not know how to fix the value of the promise.

**query.js**

```
  const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

  const vertodo = async function(req){
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
      host: '192.168.0.222',
      port: 3306,
      user: 'root',
      database: 'project',
      password : '123456789'
    });
    return  [rows, fields] = await connection.query('Select COUNT(*) total from table1 where id=' +req.id);  
    connection.end();
  }
  module.exports.vertodo = vertodo;
```

**index.js**

```
const  data_mysql  = require("./query")

// value jsonObj
// [{ id: 1,
//   name: 'XTRA',
//   proceso: 0
// },
//  { id: 2,
//   name: 'Maq',
//   proceso: 0
// }]

for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
  //jsonObj[i].proceso = 0;  
  jsonObj[i].procesa = data_mysql.vertodo(jsonObj[i]).then( rows =>{
    return rows[0][0].total
  })
  // jsonObj[i].proceso = Promise { 61 } , Promise { 33 };  

}
setTimeout(function(){
   for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
     console.log(jsonObj[i].procesa); // Promise { 61}, Promise { 33 }
   }
 }, 3000);
```

I do not know how I can solve it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your function "vertodo" returns a promise. You need to wait for the promise to resolve with the query response data. The easiest way to do this is to use the async/await syntax. See below.

**index.js**

```
const  data_mysql  = require("./query")

runQuery()
async function runQuery() {
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
        //jsonObj[i].proceso = 0;  
        queryResponse = await data_mysql.vertodo(jsonObj[i])
        // process queryResponse

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you want to do, but I assume that you want to run those queries in loop and wait until all finish and then log results.

If those queries need to be run in sequence.

```
async function runQueries() {
    for (const item of jsonObj) {
        item.procesa = await data_mysql.vertodo(item);
    }
}

runQueries.then(function () {
    jsonObj.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(item.procesa);
    });
});
```